# Equal elements in SubArray

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

I have an array containing N elements and I need to find the distance between the **index of equal** elements in a subarray; which we will get in form of query (L R) where L is starting index of subarray and R in ending index.
Total No. of array elements can be **N<=10^5** and Queries **Q<=10^5**.

**ex:**

```
7

0 4 0 8 0 32 0

2

0 2

0 5
```

//answer for 1st query will be 2 (index 2-0)

//answer for 2nd query will be 8 (index (2-0) + (4-2) + (4-0))

**Edit**: I am not expecting code (though it would be really helpful) general idea to solve will be a great help.

Comment: If you don't expect code, don't add programming language tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for the sqrt decomposition.

We want to maintain state that allows us to answer the current range and to adjust endpoints of the current range up or down one. To that end, we maintain a map from element to (sum of all indexes of that element in the current range, number of occurrences in the current range). We also maintain the current answer. To adjust the lower endpoint down to include an element x at index i, we increment the answer by sum of indexes in range - (#occurrences of x in range * i), then increment the sum and the number of occurrences. The other three operations are similar.

To achieve the sqrt decomposition, we sort the queries by (lower endpoint floor divided by sqrt N, upper endpoint) and adjust the range in order.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map whose key are the elements of the array and values are lists of the position they appear in (your example would become `{0: [0, 2, 4, 6], 8: [3], 4: [1], 32: [5]}`). These groups form unrelated problems. One way finding the answer is to see them as [maximum flow problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) where each index form *two* vertices.
Each index is connected to all the indexes following it and all the indexes preceding it are connected to it. The weight of the edges is the distance of the elements in the array, i.e. the difference between the two indexes. All the "source" vertices are connected to an infinite source and all the "destination" vertices are connected to a sink.
The sum of the values of the maximum flows for all the problems is the sum you are looking for.

As an example, let's use the indexes for the item `0`:

```
           +-------- 0 ----------+      0 --------+
           |                     |                |
           |                     |                |
Source ----+-------- 2 -------+  +----> 2 --------+---- Sink
           |                  |  |                |
           |                  |  |                |
           +-------- 4 ----+  +--+----> 4 --------+
           |               |  |  |                |
           |               |  |  |                |
           +-------- 6     +--+--+----> 6 --------+


Weight of arc (u, v) = v - u
```

Note that the number of edges grows as V^2 because every edge corresponds to a difference you have to do in order to compute the result, which are between each index and all its successors. This makes the complexity of the solution O(n^3) which is even worse than the naive algorithm, it's just a nice way of viewing things from another perspective :)